# Rename a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

I have a table with column name as "name" and I want to change it to "Student_Name" for this i used the query

[image: Showing Customer Table]

```
ALTER TABLE  "Science_Class" RENAME column name TO Student_Name;
```

[image: Showing Error Message]

But I am getting the error message as the name column doesn't exit.